# Android retrieve google play account with which the app was downloaded

Tags: android, google-play, google-account

When my application is launched, I would like to retrieve the google play account of user which was used to download the app. With that e-mail id, I would bind the user to the device.
Can anyone pls let me know how to retrieve the e-mail which was used to download the app?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

All Google accounts are stored on the device; just read that, I've seen permissions to do it, but I haven't done the code myself. After that, send the data to your DB along with the UUID and store them. Word of warning though...this method is not very popular with customers as they find it too restrictive. You have to allow for multiple devices with the same account on it. Storing customer information must be encrypted(REQUIRED BY LAW).

Comment: I am able to retrieve all google accounts associated with the device, but I want the one used to download my app.

Comment: You can have as many google accounts as you want on the device.

Comment: I know that, but I dont know anyone with more than 1 on any device.